# Jetpack Compose LazyColumn with DiffUtils animations

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I found an official example from Google that they suggest using.  However, having tested it, it does not work entirely correctly.  When shuffling and adding an element to the list it works fine.  However, the delete operation does not work correctly, and after several deletions of elements the list is completely cleared.

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1963879/5/compose/foundation/foundation/integration-tests/foundation-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/demos/AnimatedLazyColumnDemo.kt#225

I think a working implementation of this code would be useful, so I would welcome any hints as to why this might not work.

Comment: Do you want complete example or just want to get animated lazy column?

Comment: @ChiragThummar I would like to get animations of elements for deleting/adding/moving that can be integrated into LazyColumn, as done in the example from Google. Their solution seems to me the most concise, but the error I described does not allow me to use it.